# PHP - Sending post request through my server

Tags: php, curl, https

I want to use Google Services such as reCaptcha, and I got a problem on PHP which doesn't work to me when sending https requests to Google.

From what I understood, I needed to enable the cUrl extension and I enabled it in the php.ini. However, the problem wasn't solved.

I'll be glad if anyone can guide me through the process of sending a https request through PHP

Comment: Have you restart your XAMPP/WAMP/LAMP server after enable curl

Comment: no.. I'm quite new in this subject

Comment: Just restart your server

Comment: well... I don't know how to start a server... ;-;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$url = 'url.php';

$fields = ['Code' => "1", 'Sequence' => "1"];

$postvars = http_build_query($fields);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in (path)/recaptcha_verifier.php on line 20

Comment: @Bulletproof Curl extension needs to be initialized.

Comment: how can I do this? I enabled it at php.ini and yet it doesn't work

Comment: @Bulletproof you use xampp ?

Comment: @Bulletproof https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html
As a beginner you should use this.

Comment: nevermind dude. thanks for the code :) I tried that on a free host it and worked well :) thanks!!!